# Barefoot more Details Road ID

Tags: openstreetmap, road, nominatim

I currently using Barefoot (https://github.com/bmwcarit/barefoot) for several Route Matching tasks.

The installation and usage of Barefoot just worked fine. The matching already works and I got some good results.

Now I would like to get additional information about the matched roads. Barefoot returns data like this (slimjson mode) :

```
 ... {
    "route": "LINESTRING (106.89085170694243 -6.142643394836986, 106.89085170694243 -6.142643394836986)",
    "road": 1199220,
    "frac": 0.7514822019311651
} ...
```

I would like to request information like speed level or road type. How can I retrieve this kind of information. Is there a way to query for example Nominatim?

What kind of Road ID is the returned one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a really nice and fast answer by opening an issue on the barefoot repo.

Please look at https://github.com/bmwcarit/barefoot/issues/13

The key was to look up the matching between the internal id and the osm id by execute a query.

```
select gid,osm_id from bfmap_ways where gid=1;
select tags from ways where id=99;
```